# VBA Write line at once in CSV format for large volume

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access, large-data-volumes

Good day!

In VBA I have to write into a CSV file a large array. To increase speed of writing I want to write a line at once to avoid looping over each field.
The solution with looping works.
The solution with line at once inserts more or less quotes (") then it is required.

```
Dim WrdArray() As String
Dim ArrayOut(10) As String 'Required for 10000000 rows
Dim line As String
line = "A|B|C|D|E|F|Z|H|I|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|V|X"

'Simulate content
For i = 1 To 10
    ArrayOut(i) = line
Next

'->SOLUTION 1 line in loop
Filename = "C:" & "\Temp\line_in_loop.csv"
Open Filename For Output As #1

For r = LBound(ArrayOut) To UBound(ArrayOut)
    WrdArray() = Split(ArrayOut(r), "|")
    For i = LBound(WrdArray) To UBound(WrdArray) 'This loop is time consuming
        If i < UBound(WrdArray) Then
            Write #1, WrdArray(i),
        Else
            Write #1, WrdArray(i)
        End If
    Next
Next
Close #1

'line_in_loop.csv: "A","B","C","D" ...
'That is correct
'<-SOLUTION 1 line in loop

'->SOLUTION 2 line at once

Filename = "C:" & "\Temp\line_at_once.csv"
Open Filename For Output As #1
For i = 1 To UBound(ArrayOut)
    line = Replace(ArrayOut(i), "|", Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34))
    Write #1, "V1:", line
    line = Replace(ArrayOut(i), "|", ",")
    Write #1, "V2:", line
Next
Close #1

'line_at_once.csv: "V1:","A"",""B"",""C"",""D"",""E""...
'line_at_once.csv: "V2:","A,B,C,D,E ...

'How to provide write line_at_once.csv in format?: "A","B","C","D" ...

'<-SOLUTION 2 line at once
```

The code is provided [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/47vccnlct6zzrxa/CSV_line_at_once.accdb?dl=0), CSV_line_at_once.accdb, Module1.

How to write line at once in line_at_once.csv in following CSV format?: "A","B","C","D" ...

Please help.

Thanks.

```
'->SOLUTION 3 line at once - SOLVED as answered below!
Filename = "C:" & "\Temp\line_at_once.csv"
Open Filename For Output As #1
For i = 1 To UBound(ArrayOut)
line = Replace(ArrayOut(i), "|", Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34))
line = Chr(34) & line & Chr(34)
Print #1, line
Next
Close #1
'<-SOLUTION 3 line at once - SOLVED as answered below!
```

I found also an additional solution with FSO and looping by lines.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198715.aspx

```
'->SOLUTION 4 Save CSV, line loop with FSO
'Dim WrdArray() As String
Dim ArrayOut(10) As String 'Required for 10000000 rows
Dim line As String
line = "A|B|C|D|E|F|Z|H|I|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|V|X"

'Simulate content
For i = 1 To UBound(ArrayOut)
    ArrayOut(i) = line
Next

'https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198715.aspx
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Temp\fso_line_loop.csv")
For i = 1 To UBound(ArrayOut)
    line = ArrayOut(i)
    line = Replace(line, "|", Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34))
    line = Chr(34) & line & Chr(34)
    ArrayOut(i) = line
    objFile.WriteLine (ArrayOut(i))
Next
objFile.Close
'<-SOLUTION 4 Save CSV, line loop with FSO
```

I am still looking for the fastest way which I think is saving at once the entire array ArrayOut() without looping.

The below code SOLUTION 5 does not work.

Please help.

```
'->SOLUTION 5 Does not work. Please help.
Print #1, ArrayOut() 'case A
objFile.WriteLine (ArrayOut()) 'case B
```

Comment: you should use print instead of write. Write tends to put extra quotes :)

Comment: I added: line = Chr(34) & line & Chr(34).  Print #1, line. It works!

Comment: glad you figured it out

Comment: If you are looking for performance with large volume, you should stop using VBA. It is very slow compared to the speed you can achieve using VB.NET (which is free)

Comment: Is this question still open? It's a little unclear. If yes, what is the actual, current question?

Comment: This question is still open. Solutions 1-4 solve the issue but in loop, record by record. It works but it is slow for large data. The code is necessary in VBA because it is part of a MS Access. To save a file with 10 millions records takes 10-15 minute and generates a file of 100 MB. The PC is very fast CPU I7, SSD it copies in File Explorer a file of 100 MB in a second, on the other side generation of 100 MB takes 10-15 minutes. To avoid loop, I am asking how the entire ArrayOut() can be copied at once in a CSV(text file).